# Office Word Interop issue caused by Microsoft Update

Tags: .net, vb.net, office-interop

I have a problem with a Windows Forms application written in VB.Net (I didn't write it, trying to troubleshoot it). One part of the application uses the Word Interop assembly to do a mail merge between a Word document and a text file containing the data.

A couple of days ago Microsoft pushed out an update for Word ([KB2883013](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/MS14-061)), which caused the mail merge to stop working. The Word doc simply prints out with no data. I am stumped as to what I can do to resolve this issue.

I tried running the application as administrator, I tried copying the Interop dlls directly to the project folder, but neither made a difference (not that I really thought it would, just didn't really know what else to try). The only thing that worked was to actually uninstall the update, but it's just going to happen again next week with the next round of automatic updates. The code for the mail merge is below, any advice would be greatly appreciated, I don't even really know where to begin fixing this issue. The Word doc and data files are both located in the AppData folder.

```
        wordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=returnAppPath() & "mergedoc.doc")

        wordApp.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource(Name:= _
            returnAppPath() & "inputdata.txt", _
            ConfirmConversions:=False, ReadOnly:=False, LinkToSource:=True, _
            AddToRecentFiles:=False, PasswordDocument:="", PasswordTemplate:="", _
            WritePasswordDocument:="", WritePasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, _
            Format:=Word.WdOpenFormat.wdOpenFormatAuto, Connection:="", SQLStatement:="", SQLStatement1 _
            :="", SubType:=Word.WdMergeSubType.wdMergeSubTypeOther)

        With wordApp.ActiveDocument.MailMerge
            .Destination = Word.WdMailMergeDestination.wdSendToNewDocument
            .SuppressBlankLines = True
            With .DataSource
                .FirstRecord = Word.WdMailMergeDefaultRecord.wdDefaultFirstRecord
                .LastRecord = Word.WdMailMergeDefaultRecord.wdDefaultLastRecord
            End With
            .Execute(Pause:=False)
        End With
        Dim intCopies As Integer = CInt(numudCopies.Value)

        wordApp.Application.PrintOut(FileName:="", Range:=Word.WdPrintOutRange.wdPrintAllDocument, Item:= _
            Word.WdPrintOutItem.wdPrintDocumentContent, Copies:=CObj(intCopies), Pages:="", PageType:=Word.WdPrintOutPages.wdPrintAllPages, _
            ManualDuplexPrint:=False, Collate:=True, Background:=True, PrintToFile:= _
            False, PrintZoomColumn:=0, PrintZoomRow:=0, PrintZoomPaperWidth:=0, _
            PrintZoomPaperHeight:=0)

        wordApp.ActiveWindow.Close(False)
        wordApp.ActiveDocument.Close(SaveChanges:=Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges)
        wordApp.Quit()
        wordApp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Interop is not a good idea in certain scenarios anyway (see Microsoft's KB 257757).

One option in your scenario is to recreate a template and do mail merging programmatically using some OpenXML toolkits. In this way you will achieve several benefits:

- templates can be prepared in Word using Add-in for data placeholders
- final documents will be in docx, which can be used with all versions of Office since 2003
- you can merge data in all parts of the document (including headers, footers, sections)
- data can be shown/omitted based on conditional criteria.
- report generation can be done centrally on a server, no Word installation is necessary.

In your .NET application you have to read data into .NET objects (collections of data model classes) and then send them to the document generation method which prepares the final document where template and data get merged together. My tool of choice for this is Docentric and since I started to use it I didn't have to do any more plain Word mail merging or VBA document scripts for complex document manipulations. You can take a closer look at a practical example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/759408/Creating-Word-documents-in-Net-using-Docentric-Too).